# Android map v2 draw custom rectangle

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm new to the google maps v2, I need to draw a rectangle from point1 to point2, with a custom color and width, I tried to use a Polyline, but all the labels (city name, country name ..) are still visible, so how can I do this ?

thank you

this is what I tried

```
mMapView.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
.add(new LatLng(xx,xx), new LatLng(xx,xx))
.width(50)
.color(Color.parseColor("#f4f3f0")));
```

Comment: You simply can create a line between two points.

Comment: how can I do it, the line I know is Polyline wich is not working correctly

Comment: Also check out my post over here ..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android/20901610#20901610 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034636/implementing-google-places-api/21036171#21036171

Comment: Also check out my post over here ..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android/20901610#20901610 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034636/implementing-google-places-api/21036171#21036171

Comment: If your code does not work, you should post it

Answer (score 2):

Just read the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline)

**Example**

```
GoogleMap map;
// ... get a map.
// Add a thin red line from London to New York.
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
   .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
   .width(5)
   .color(Color.RED));
```

Comment: polyline does not hide city names, it is drawn below them

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
public class My_Map extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));

    // Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the map.
    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
            .add(new LatLng(-33.866, 151.195))  
            .add(new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431)) 
            .add(new LatLng(21.291, -157.821))  
            .add(new LatLng(37.423, -122.091))  
    );
}
}
```

For more details just check [How to draw free hand polygon in Google map V2 in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android/20901610#20901610)